# TreeView com Nodes & Childs através de base de dados SQL

Tags: c#, treeview

Gostaria de saber como posso popular uma `TreeView` com Nodes e Childs através de uma conexão de SQL. A conexão já está feita este é o código que tenho para já, mas não funciona pois adiciona apenas uma node que é a primeira da lista.

n01 - ParentNode 
n02 - ChildNode

```
foreach (DataRow dr in tb.Rows)
{
    if (treeView_menus.Nodes.Count > 0)
    {
        if (treeView_menus.TopNode.Tag == dr.ItemArray[1])
        {
            TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
            node.Tag = dr["Id02"];
            node.Text = dr["n02"].ToString();

            treeView_menus.Nodes[dr["n01"].ToString()].Nodes.Add(node);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
        node.Tag = dr["Id01"];
        node.Text = dr["n01"].ToString();
        treeView_menus.Nodes.Add(node);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz esse método que uso há alguns anos, e até por isso ainda utilizava um DataTable como entrada dos dados, se fosse fazer novamente, utilizaria uma List de um objeto. Seria mais fácil.

> Você pode aproveitar a lógica de preencher a treeview, mas recomendo não utilizar DataTable e adequar para uma lista tipada.

```
public static void PreencherMenu(DataTable dtMenu, TreeView tree)
{
    if (tree != null)
    {    
        tree.Nodes.Clear();

        dtMenu.DefaultView.Sort = "nivel, ordem";
        dtMenu = dtMenu.DefaultView.ToTable();

        foreach (DataRow r in dtMenu.Rows)
        {
            string nome = r["nome"].ToString();
            string pai = r["pai"].ToString();

            TreeNode t = new TreeNode(r["texto"].ToString());
            t.ImageKey = r["img"].ToString();
            t.SelectedImageKey = r["simg"].ToString();
            t.Name = r["nome"].ToString();
            t.Text = r["texto"].ToString();
            t.Tag = String.IsNullOrEmpty(r["tag"].ToString()) ? null : r["tag"].ToString();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pai))
            {
                tree.Nodes.Add(t);
            }
            else
            {
                TreeNode[] parent = tree.Nodes.Find(pai, true);
                if (parent.Length != 0)
                {
                    parent[0].Nodes.Add(t);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

A tabela de entrada, deve ter o seguinte formato:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("texto"); //Texto de Exibição do item
dt.Columns.Add("nome");  //Nome do item (chave) deve ser único
dt.Columns.Add("pai");   //Nome do item pai do item atual, se não houver um pai, informar null
dt.Columns.Add("img");   //Index de uma imagem a ser usada em um imagelist associado ao controle
dt.Columns.Add("simg");  //Index de uma imagem a ser usada em um imagelist associado ao controle (quando o item for selecionado)
dt.Columns.Add("tag");   //Tag associada ao item
dt.Columns.Add("nivel", typeof(Int32));//Nivel do item (0 = Raiz)
dt.Columns.Add("ordem", typeof(Int32));//Ordem que o item deve aparecer

dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns["nome"] };
```

Exemplo de um menu Cadastro:

```
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Cadastros", "cadastros", null, "Folder-Close.png", "Folder-Open.png", null, 0, 1 });

dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Pessoas / Convênios", "pessoas", "cadastros", "Clients-icon.png", "Clients-icon.png", null, 1, 1 });
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou ver o que consigo fazer. :)